# Sina Weibo's short url?

Tags: short-url, sinaweibo

When browsing sina weibo, one of a typical weibo message's url looks like this:

```
http://weibo.com/1887344341/Dr3jyu3tp
```

Where 1887344341 is the User ID. I'm not clear what is Dr3jyu3tp and how did we get that. Is it a shorten version for message id?

Checked their API docs, http://open.weibo.com/wiki/2/statuses/show but could't find it. Is it 'idstr'?

Answer (score 1):

You can [reference the API](http://open.weibo.com/wiki/2/statuses/go). The URL to a specific weibo post will be `http://api.weibo.com/2/statuses/go?uid=[USER_ID]&id=[POST_ID]`.